# Find which group box is enabled and which is not

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form which contains more than 4 group boxes.Each group box has some text fields.What I am seeking is to get values from only that group box which is enabled. So my question is : Is it possible to scan all the available group boxes to find out if any of them is enabled and if one of them is enabled get and save values from only that group box into the database?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to find all enabled group boxes dynamically, but why not manually check `Enabled` property of each `GroupBox` control? What's the benefit of making it dynamic? What do you want to do with controls of those enabled group boxes after you find them and how do you want to feed those values to database.

Comment: What actually i want is i have a combo box. depending upon the selection of it i want pop up a new form which has multiple group box with separate text boxes. So when the user fills up textboxes in an enabled group box i just want to save those values..... i don't wanna write code that will check all the text values from other disabled group boxes too... this will cause unnecessary and redundant code writing....

Comment: For example you have 3 textboxes in groupbox1, 5 textboxes in grouupbox2. So how would you write a dynamic code to read values and assign them to different commands to save in db. Detecting enabled groupbox is not hard. But your question seems to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and probably your original requirement needs a different solution.

Comment: @ Reza Aghaei So what would you do to solve my requirement..if a different logic can solve my problem please.....throw it to me m eagerly looking for it..

Comment: First we should know your problem description and your actual requirement.

Comment: Ok. so my exact problem is........the commonly used properties like name,activities,address,total person, event details etc. are kept in one single main form. the properties which are not commonly required such as weight of item,its units (kg,liter,total cost of the item etc.), total rescued etc. are kept in pop up form. Now when the activity type selected from combo box needs the user to enter weights ,its units etc respective group box  containing it should be enabled and entered values in those text fields should only be read and saved to the database..!!!

Comment: Use data-binding. Bind those controls to the object or data table which you are editing, then without any additional code your data that you enter in form will go to data source and then you can simply save the data source.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan the controls like this:

```
GroupBox gBox = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Enabled);

List<string> values = new List<string>();
if(gBox != null)
{
    foreach(var txtBox in gBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        values.Add(txtBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Note this assumes that the `GroupBoxes` are added directly to the form, and not to any panel. Also the `TextBoxes` are added directly to the `GroupBox` with no additional panels.

Alternatively, you can do it in one go:

```
List<string> result = this.Controls.OfType<GroupBox>()
                                    .Where(gBox => gBox.Enabled)
                                    .SelectMany(gBox => gBox.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
                                    .Select(txtBox => txtBox.Text).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *Linq*; providing that `GroupBox`es are placed *directly* on the form and `TextBox` of interest are *directly* on their `GroupBox`es:

```
  string[] values = Controls
    .OfType<GroupBox>()
    .Where(box => box.Enabled)
    .SelectMany(box => box
       .Controls
       .OfType<TextBox>()
       .Select(tb => tb.Text))
    .ToArray();
```